# Math operation on JSON response in karate DSL

Tags: testing, automated-tests, karate

From the below response, How can I calculate the total rate dynamically?

```json
[
  { 
 "name": "Income Tax",
 "rate": 20 
  },
  {
 "name": "Sales Tax",
 "rate": 8 
  },
  {
 "name": "Property Tax",
 "rate": 2 
  },
  {
 "name": "Corporate Tax", 
 "rate": 15 
  },
  {
 "name": "Excise Tax",
 "rate": 5 
  }
]
```

I have tried adding each rate value but I’m looking for smart answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
* def total = 0    
* def response = [ { "name": "Income Tax", "rate": 20 }, { "name": "Sales Tax", "rate": 8 }, { "name": "Property Tax", "rate": 2 }, { "name": "Corporate Tax", "rate": 15 }, { "name": "Excise Tax", "rate": 5 } ]
* response.forEach(x => total = total + x.rate)
* print total
```